# Change content of anchor element on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an image tag inside my anchor tag

```
<a href="#"><img src="a.png">My Link</img></a>
```

Is it possible that, when hovering my anchor tag, the image can be switched to b.png, but then back to a.png after unhovering?

As of now what i am trying is

```
<img onMouseOver="b.png">
```

but the problem is, after hovering the anchor tag, it doesn't change back.

Comment: what is that `a.png` can you show screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

- Hide the second image with `display: none`.
- On hover, show the second image and hide the first image with `display: none`.

```css
img:last-child          { display: none;  }
a:hover img:last-child  { display: block; }
a:hover img:first-child { display: none;  }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f00/fff">
</a>
```